# Getting react-router-dom useBeforeUnload to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app using `react-router-dom@6.10` (plain web app, react vanilla, no NextJs). I'm attempting to stop a user from leaving the page when he has unsaved changes.  I copied the code here to see if useBeforeUnload works:
`"https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-before-unload"`

However the code inside of `useBeforeUnload` does not trigger when I navigate away from the page.

My react-router is defined using `<BrowserRouter>`.  Do I instead need to use `createBrowserRouter`?

Everything else in my app is working fine.

Comment: The `window.onbeforeunload` event isn't the same thing as a React component unmounting. It's like when the user reloads the page or navigates away from the app. Navigating to pages ***within*** your React app doesn't unload the document. `useBeforeUnload` only takes a callback to "do an action", e.g. save to localStorage, *just* prior to the page unloading. It's not designed to block the UI. Additionally, it's become considered poor UI/UX to "trap" users on your page and block/keep them from navigating away when they want to.

Comment: You might be looking for the [`useBlocker`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L855-L895) or [usePrompt](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/a44859fbd800e45c1a2523b6e1fd33b3d76811f6/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L1289-L1318) hooks instead. Note that these hooks are not publicly documented and aren't really recommended to be used and are only offered as an "escape hatch". In fact, `usePrompt` is exported as `unstable_usePrompt` to indicate that it could be removed at any time.

Answer (score 1):

useBeforeUnload is triggered when the page is refreshed, not when components are unloaded

Comment: is there another function that would work when any link is clicked that would change the page?